# Connecting to FTP with Python Specifying Port and USN/Passwd

Tags: python

I would like to specify the port to the ftp client, in addition to submitting a USN and password combination.  The two options I've been trying look like this

```
#no port specified
ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, username, password)

#port specified
ftp = ftplib.FTP(username, password, source_address = (host, port))
```

However, the second doesn't work.  Help?

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use the `connect` and `login` methods: `ftp = ftplib.FTP(); ftp.connect(host, port); ftp.login(username, password)`

Comment: Seems like it.  Was trying to find a way to not have to do it separately.  I feel like I'm not understanding fully what the source_address query is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection process makes more sense when broken down into pieces

```
import ftplib

# create a new FTP() instance
f = ftplib.FTP()

# connect to our FTP site
f.connect(host,port)

# log into the FTP site
f.login(username, password)
```